# How to convert or parse the response from the webservice to a String Array?

Tags: java, android, web-services, arrays

I return a String[] array from the webservice. And in my Android App I get the response like this:

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = false;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL,60000);

androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

Vector<?> response = (Vector<?>) envelope.getResponse();

String sTripResponse = response.toString();
System.out.println("My Response: \n" + response.toString());
```

And this is the string of the response:

```
02-06 12:58:23.729: I/System.out(8239): [1#1040#2014-02-04#2014-02-04#16:50:17#16:55:47#Ranshofen#Braunau am Inn#0#292608#0.383901696, 2#1040#2014-02-04#2014-02-05#16:55:47#07:54:26#Braunau am Inn#Ranshofen#0#390144#0.512259072]
```

And I want to bring this response in a String Array, but I dont know how to do this.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this may helps you

```
String sTripResponse = response.toString();
    String finalString = sTripResponse.substring(1, sTripResponse.length() - 1);
    String[] arr = finalString.split("#");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("" + arr[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] oK = Response.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").split(",");
```